# Gmail and Thunderbird IMAP behavior

Tags: gmail, imap, thunderbird

I am not sure if I can implement what I want but seems to me a logical idea also if is not working.
The main problem I have is that deleting an email from the email server (using its webmail) the same email will be deleted for every IMAP client.

This is what I am doing and what I want using a gmail account:

1. I want to retrieve the emails from an account on some PCs, it is an account common to a team or a department as may be accounting@acme.com (so I have to use IMAP)
2. The gmail account is set to permit the use of IMAP and POP3
3. My email client is Mozilla Thunderbird (but everything may work with other clients)
4. I want that deleting an email on the IMAP client does not delete the same email on the server.
5. I want that deleting an email on the server does not delete the same email on the IMAP clients.
6. I want that the user may set Thunderbird to save locally the emails as a POP3 client would do but without deleting the emails from the server.

Any help will be appreciated.
Massimo

Comment: take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/369737/thunderbird-do-not-delete-local-copies-of-imap-messages